# Calculating double sum: $\sum_{k,l\ge1} \frac{l(l+1)}{k^n(k+l)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to calculate the value of $$\sum_{k,l\ge1} \frac{l(l+1)}{k^n(k+l)^2}$$ Here's my attempt so far:
$$\sum_{k,l\ge1} \frac{l(l+1)}{k^n(k+l)^2} = \sum_{k,l\ge1}\frac{1}{k^{n-1}(k+l)}\left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+l} \right) + \sum_{k,l\ge1}\frac{1}{k^{n-2}}\left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+l} \right)^2 =  $$
$$ =\sum_{k,l\ge1} \left(\frac{1}{k^n(k+l)} - \frac{1}{k^{n-1}(k+l)^2} +\frac{1}{k^n} -\frac{2}{k^{n-1}(k+l)} + \frac{1}{k^{n-2}(k+l)^2} \right)$$
From this I can see the the values of some of these terms i.e. $\zeta(n) , \zeta(2,n-1)$ and $\zeta(2,n-2)$ However I'm not sure how to deal with 
$$\sum_{k,l\ge1}\left(\frac{1}{k^n(k+l)}-\frac{2}{k^{n-1}(k+l)} \right)$$
and I was hoping for some hints or maybe even a better approach to the whole calculation.

Comment: How are we defining this summation?  If it's in the usual sense (as a limit of partial sums in some sense), then you can see the limit is divergent just by $$\lim_{l\to\infty} \frac{l(l+1)}{k^n(k+l)^2} = \frac{1}{k^n} > 0$$

Comment: Oh yes of course, thank you very much!